# How can I set ".indexOn" for all child keys in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the follow data structure in Firebase Realtime Database.

```
{
   groups: {
      $groupid: {
        $userid: Boolean
      }
   }
}
```

Here `#groupid` and `$userid` vary.
When a user with id "user0" is in the group "group0", it will be

```
{
   groups: {
    ...
    group0: {
       user0: true
    }
    ...
   }
}
```

When the user is removed, it will be `user0: false`.
When I query groups with a specific user, `Firebase SDK` shows a warning:
`FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "user0" at /groups to your security rules for better performance`

As the user id varies, I think all user ids should be indexed on.
How can I write a relevant security rule?

Comment: There is no way to define a wildcard index. Wanting to do so typically means that you've inverted your data structure. Yours looks similar to the categorization problem I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query groups with a specific user, it is better to make a user maintain group list.

```
{
    user-groups: {
        user0: {
            group0: true,
            group1: true
        }
    }
}
```

So, a group has its members and a user has groups he/she belongs to.